# How can I tell when a FileHandle has nothing left to be read?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nstask, nsfilehandle, nspipe

I'm trying to use a [`Pipe`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/pipe)'s [`fileHandleForReading`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/pipe/1414352-filehandleforreading)'s [`readabilityHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle/1412413-readabilityhandler) to read both the [`standardOutput`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1407627-standardoutput) and [`standardError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1414916-standarderror) of a [`Process`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process). However, the moment the [`terminationHandler`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process/1408746-terminationhandler) is called is actually *before* the moment my `readabilityHandler` is called for the first time.

I'm not sure why the process does this, but it means I'm not getting all the data, because I assume process termination means all output has been flushed to the pipe. Since this isn't the case, **is there a way for me to tell when there is no more output to be read?** I assume that involves checking if a [`FileHandle`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filehandle) is still open, but I don't see an API for that.

Here's an example of the basic idea of what my code looks like:

```swift
let stdOutPipe = Pipe()
let stdErrPipe = Pipe()

stdOutPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { stdOutFileHandle in
    let stdOutPartialData = stdOutFileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()

    guard !stdOutPartialData.isEmpty else {
        print("Time to read, but nothing to be read?") // happens a lot
        return
    }

    self.tempStdOutStorage.append(stdOutPartialData)
}

stdErrPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { stdErrFileHandle in
    let stdErrPartialData = stdErrFileHandle.readDataToEndOfFile()

    guard !stdErrPartialData.isEmpty else {
        print("Time to read, but nothing to be read?") // happens a lot
        return
    }

    self.tempStdErrStorage.append(stdErrPartialData)
}

process.standardOutput = stdOutPipe
process.standardError = stdErrPipe


process.terminationHandler = { process in
    notifyOfCompleteRead(stdOut: self.tempStdOutStorage, stdErr: self.tempStdErrStorage)
}

mySpecializedDispatchQueue.async(execute: process.launch)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the `readabilityHandler` you should use `availableData` to get the
currently available data without blocking. Empty available data indicates EOF
on the file handle, in that case the readability handler should be removed.

A dispatch group can be used to wait for EOF on both standard output and standard error after the process has finished.

Example:

```
let group = DispatchGroup()

group.enter()
stdOutPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { stdOutFileHandle in
    let stdOutPartialData = stdOutFileHandle.availableData
    if stdOutPartialData.isEmpty  {
        print("EOF on stdin")
        stdOutPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = nil
        group.leave()
    } else {
        tempStdOutStorage.append(stdOutPartialData)
    }
}

group.enter()
stdErrPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { stdErrFileHandle in
    let stdErrPartialData = stdErrFileHandle.availableData

    if stdErrPartialData.isEmpty  {
        print("EOF on stderr")
        stdErrPipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = nil
        group.leave()
    } else {
        tempStdErrStorage.append(stdErrPartialData)
    }
}

process.standardOutput = stdOutPipe
process.standardError = stdErrPipe

process.launch()

process.terminationHandler = { process in
    group.wait()
    print("OUTPUT:", String(data: tempStdOutStorage, encoding: .utf8)!)
    print("ERROR: ", String(data: tempStdErrStorage, encoding: .utf8)!)
}
```

Comment: I just tryed it and according to logs. I can receive more data, after `availableData` was empty. So I'm not sure that this answer is correct one

Comment: @Nikolay: That is strange, I am fairly sure that it is correct. I have tested the code once more and it behaved as described. I cannot explain why you observed a different behavior.

Comment: thank you for reply, I just tryed to create isolated sample to demonstrate the issue, and it works fine. So I think that issue might be specifically in my implementation, rather that in provided sample.