# More Buffer for FileHandler Output?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos

I have the following Code:

```
func syncShellExec(path: String, args: [String] = []) {
    let process            = Process()
    process.launchPath     = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments      = [path] + args
    let outputPipe         = Pipe()
    let filelHandler       = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe
    process.launch()

    filelHandler.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
        let data = pipe.availableData
        if let line = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.output_window.string += line
                self.output_window.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error decoding data: \(data.base64EncodedString())")
        }
    }
    process.waitUntilExit()
    filelHandler.readabilityHandler = nil
}
```

If the amount of round about 330.000 Characters is reached the output stopped immediately. Is there a way to increase the Buffer for this Operation?

Comment: I assume that the problem is that the process terminates before all data has been read from the pipe. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/52336340/1187415 for a possible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems:

- The process may terminate before all data has been read from the pipe.
- Your function blocks the main thread, so that the UI eventually freezes.

Similarly as in [How can I tell when a FileHandle has nothing left to be read?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335435/how-can-i-tell-when-a-filehandle-has-nothing-left-to-be-read/52336340#52336340) you should wait asynchronously for the process to terminate, and also wait for “end-of-file” on the pipe:

```
func asyncShellExec(path: String, args: [String] = []) {
    let process            = Process()
    process.launchPath     = "/bin/bash"
    process.arguments      = [path] + args
    let outputPipe         = Pipe()
    let filelHandler       = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe
    process.launch()

    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    filelHandler.readabilityHandler = { pipe in
        let data = pipe.availableData
        if data.isEmpty { // EOF
            filelHandler.readabilityHandler = nil
            group.leave()
            return
        }

        if let line = String(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
            DispatchQueue.main.sync {
                self.output_window.string += line
                self.output_window.scrollToEndOfDocument(nil)
            }
        } else {
            print("Error decoding data: \(data.base64EncodedString())")
        }
    }

    process.terminationHandler = { process in
        group.wait()
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            // Update UI that process has finished.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The same behaviour. It stops Output after a certain character amount. And it freezes the GUI of the App until end of process.

Comment: I´m executing "unrar" via bash.

Comment: @Sascha7777: The problem could be that the function blocks the main thread. What happens if you remove `group.wait()` and  `process.waitUntilExit()` ?

Comment: Thank you. That works perfectly. No freezing GUI and it outputs until the command is done.

Comment: @Sascha7777: I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Tried your updated answer. It doesn´t work this way. With only process.launch() // Start process at the end it works.