# read process standardOutput and standardError in parallel in swift without blocking

Tags: swift, multithreading, macos, asynchronous, concurrency

In swift5 would like to run a `Process()` read both `standardOutput` and `standardError` without blocking, so I can parse them.

This example code once the line with `for try await line in errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines` is called, the program execution is blocked.  The standardOutput reader stops printing

```swift
import Foundation

let outputPipe = Pipe()
let errorPipe = Pipe()

let process = Process()
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:"/sbin/ping")
process.arguments = ["google.com"]
process.standardOutput = outputPipe
process.standardError = errorPipe

try? process.run()

func processStdOut() async
{
  for i in 0..<5 {
    print("processStdOut X ", i)
    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 1_000_000_000)
  }

  do {
    for try await line in outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines {
      print("stdout Line: \(line)")
    }
  } catch {
    NSLog("processStdOut Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
  NSLog("processStdOut finished")

}

func processStdErr() async
{
  for i in 0..<5 {
    print("processStdErr X ", i)
    try? await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: 2_000_000_000)
  }
  do {
    for try await line in errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.bytes.lines {
      print("stderr Line: \(line)")
    }
  } catch {
    NSLog("processStdErr Error \(error.localizedDescription)")
  }
  NSLog("processStdErr finished")
}

await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
  group.addTask {
    await processStdErr()
  }
  group.addTask {
    await processStdOut()
  }
  group.addTask {
    process.waitUntilExit()
  }
}
```

Note that if you force data into standardError by disconnecting the wifi or network standardOutput is unblocked again.

Anything else I should try?

Comment: This has helped me in similar case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52335435/how-can-i-tell-when-a-filehandle-has-nothing-left-to-be-read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most programs default the default buffering policy and since you don't have control of how `/sbin/ping` handles the output one of the pipes might be blocking the `FileHandle.AsyncBytes` implementation (not sure why). I got this to work with both pipes at the same time by calling `.availableData` instead to avoid blocking.

```swift
import Foundation

let outputPipe = Pipe()
let errorPipe = Pipe()

let process = Process()

process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/sbin/ping")
process.arguments = ["-c", "10", "diariosur.es"]
process.standardOutput = outputPipe
process.standardError = errorPipe

try? process.run()

func processStdOut() async {
    print("stdout start")
    
    while process.isRunning {
        let data = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.availableData
        if !data.isEmpty {
            if let line = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
                print("stdout data: \(line)")
            }
        }
        
    }
    
    print("stdout finished")
}

func processStdErr() async {
    print("stderr start")
    
    while process.isRunning {
        let data = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading.availableData
        if !data.isEmpty {
            if let line = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines) {
                print("stderr data: \(line)")
            }
        }
    }
    
    print("stderr finished")
}
    
    await withTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
        group.addTask {
            await processStdErr()
        }
        
        group.addTask {
            await processStdOut()
        }
    }
    
    process.waitUntilExit()
```

Then I get the following (trimmed) output:

```bash
stderr start
stdout start
stdout data: PING diariosur.es (23.213.41.6): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 23.213.41.6: icmp_seq=0 ttl=57 time=7.060 ms
stdout data: 64 bytes from 23.213.41.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=6.562 ms
...
stdout data: 64 bytes from 23.213.41.6: icmp_seq=9 ttl=57 time=7.904 ms
stdout data: --- diariosur.es ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 6.562/7.327/9.439/0.783 ms
stdout finished
stderr finished
```

I tried with `curl` that defaults to `stderr` and it is not blocking either:

```swift
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/usr/bin/curl")
process.arguments = ["-N", "--output", "test.zsync", "http://ubuntu.mirror.digitalpacific.com.au/releases/23.04/ubuntu-23.04-desktop-amd64.iso.zsync"]
```

Edit:

Tested with the following C program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; ++i) {
        fprintf(stdout, "stdout: %d\n", i); 
        fflush(stdout); 
    
        if (i % 10 == 0) {
                fprintf(stderr, "stderr: %d\n", i); 
                fflush(stderr);
        }   
        usleep(100000);
    }   
    
    return 0;
}
```

It returns the following output:

```
stdout start
stderr start
stdout data: stdout: 1
stdout data: stdout: 2
stdout data: stdout: 3
stdout data: stdout: 4
stdout data: stdout: 5
stdout data: stdout: 6
stdout data: stdout: 7
stdout data: stdout: 8
stdout data: stdout: 9
stderr data: stderr: 10
stdout data: stdout: 10
stdout data: stdout: 11
stdout data: stdout: 12
stdout data: stdout: 13
stdout data: stdout: 14
stdout data: stdout: 15
stdout data: stdout: 16
stdout data: stdout: 17
stdout data: stdout: 18
stdout data: stdout: 19
stderr data: stderr: 20
```

Comment: Works by removing `FileHandle.AsyncBytes` and `lines` reading.  To be safe will have to implement own line parser.

Comment: FWIW, my experience suggests that the `bytes` problem is unrelated to flushing of the buffers. Only process `standardOutput`, and I get it as it is output. Do `standardOutput` and `standardError` and you get this blocking behavior with `bytes`. But use either your approach or `readabilityHandler` and the problem goes away.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it appears that the standard `bytes` implementation can block `standardOutput` when simultaneously using `bytes` on `standardError`, too.

Here is a simple `bytes` implementation that does not block, because it avails itself of `readabilityHandler`:

```swift
extension Pipe {
    struct AsyncBytes: AsyncSequence {
        typealias Element = UInt8

        let pipe: Pipe

        func makeAsyncIterator() -> AsyncStream<Element>.Iterator {
            AsyncStream { continuation in
                pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { @Sendable handle in
                    let data = handle.availableData

                    guard !data.isEmpty else {
                        continuation.finish()
                        return
                    }

                    for byte in data {
                        continuation.yield(byte)
                    }
                }

                continuation.onTermination = { _ in
                    pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = nil
                }
            }.makeAsyncIterator()
        }
    }

    var bytes: AsyncBytes { AsyncBytes(pipe: self) }
}
```

Thus, the following does not experience the same problem when simultaneously processing both `standardOutput` and `standardError` at the same time:

```swift
let outputPipe = Pipe()
let errorPipe = Pipe()

let process = Process()
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: …)
process.standardOutput = outputPipe
process.standardError = errorPipe

func processStandardOutput() async throws {
    for try await line in outputPipe.bytes.lines {
        …
    }
}

func processStandardError() async throws {
    for try await line in errorPipe.bytes.lines {
        …
    }
}

// optionally, you might want to return whatever non-zero termination status code the process returned

process.terminationHandler = { process in
    if process.terminationStatus != 0 {
        exit(process.terminationStatus)
    }
}

try process.run()

try? await withThrowingTaskGroup(of: Void.self) { group in
    group.addTask {
        try await processStandardOutput()
    }
    
    group.addTask {
        try await processStandardError()
    }
    
    …
}
```