# NSTask/Process + NSPipe + NSFileHandle in Modern Swift Concurrency

Tags: swift, actor, nstask, swift-concurrency, nsfilehandle

### Context

Suppose we have a Mac app that uses `Process` (formerly `NSTask`) to run some other executable which writes data to both STDOUT and STDERR. This process might take a long time to do its work. Prior to Swift Concurrency, we would do this:

```
// Assume the object with this function is bound to the MainActor:
func doSomeWork()
{
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async 
    {
        let task = Process()
            
        let errorPipe = Pipe()
        let errorFileHandle = errorPipe.fileHandleForReading
        task.standardError = errorPipe
            
        let outputPipe = Pipe()
        let outputFileHandle = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading
        task.standardOutput = outputPipe
            
        //  Need to read fileHandles because if more than 64kb of data is written, they'll block the whole thread until we read them.
        var outputData = Data(capacity: 1000)
        var errorData = Data(capacity: 1000)

        // Semaphore to make sure our readability handlers exit before we continue. NSTask does not guarantee they'll finish before -waitUntilExit fires.
        let sema = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

        outputFileHandle.readabilityHandler = { handle in
            let newData = handle.availableData()
            if newData.count == 0 {
                // end-of-data signal is an empty data object.
                outputFileHandle.readabilityHandler = nil
                sema.signal()
            } else {
                outputData.append(newData)
            }
        }

        errorFileHandle.readabilityHandler = { handle in
            let newData = handle.availableData()
            if newData.count == 0 {
                // end-of-data signal is an empty data object.
                errorFileHandle.readabilityHandler = nil
                sema.signal()
            } else {
                errorData.append(newData)
            }
        }

        task.terminationHandler = { task in
            sema.signal()
        }

        defer {
            errorFileHandle.closeFile()
            outputFileHandle.closeFile()
        }

        do {
            try task.run()
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }

        sema.wait()
        sema.wait()
        sema.wait()

        // Use outputData and errorData to do whatever...
    }

}
```

### Race Conditions

Note that the `readabilityHandlers` make no guarantee on which thread they're executed. And `Process` makes no guarantee that each `readabilityHandler` is done writing data by the time `task.terminationHandler` is called. **Process also makes no guarantee that the readabilityHandlers are finished by the time `waitUntilExit()` returns.** Do not suggest that alternative; I've been there and I have the t-shirt.

Therefore, I use a semaphore to ensure that all three pieces of the puzzle are 100% finished before I continue.

`outputData` and `errorData` are shared mutable state across threads, but because of the semaphore, it's guaranteed that nothing will read from either object until all the writes from the two `readabilityHandlers` have finished.

### Adopting Swift Concurrency

I understand that I can use an `Actor` to wrap `outputData` and `errorData` to satisfy the compiler's error about `Mutatation of captured var` outputData `in concurrently-executing code.` and formalize my currently "manual" guard against race conditions (at the expense of a lot more context-switching overhead.)

##### **QUESTION**:

In Swift concurrency, threads are always supposed to make forward progress. Which means no semaphores. So even if I move the `Process` and the `readabilityHandlers` to an `Actor`, how do I properly "await" all three pieces being done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a general rule, where we might have reached for a semaphore, we would now frequently `await` a task or continuation. If wrapping some traditional asynchronous API that does not yet support Swift concurrency, we would often do this with [`withCheckedContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedcontinuation(function:_:)) or [`withCheckedThrowingContinuation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/withcheckedthrowingcontinuation(function:_:)). But as you correctly note, we would scrupulously avoid semaphores in Swift concurrency.

But, in this case, when dealing with a series of asynchronous events, I would probably make an `AsyncSequence` for the `availableData`:

```swift
extension Pipe {
    struct AsyncAvailableData: AsyncSequence {
        typealias Element = Data

        let pipe: Pipe

        func makeAsyncIterator() -> AsyncStream<Element>.Iterator {
            AsyncStream { continuation in
                pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = { @Sendable handle in
                    let data = handle.availableData

                    guard !data.isEmpty else {
                        continuation.finish()
                        return
                    }

                    continuation.yield(data)
                }

                continuation.onTermination = { _ in
                    pipe.fileHandleForReading.readabilityHandler = nil
                }
            }.makeAsyncIterator()
        }
    }

    var availableData: AsyncAvailableData { AsyncAvailableData(pipe: self) }
}
```

I would then use `async let` ([SE-0317](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0317-async-let.md)) to run these in concurrently:

```swift
func doSomeWork() async throws {
    let process = Process()
    process.executableURL = command

    let inputPipe  = Pipe()
    let outputPipe = Pipe()
    let errorPipe  = Pipe()

    process.standardError  = errorPipe
    process.standardOutput = outputPipe
    process.standardInput  = inputPipe

    // optionally, you might want to return whatever non-zero termination status code the process returned

    process.terminationHandler = { process in
        if process.terminationStatus != 0 {
            exit(process.terminationStatus)
        }
    }

    async let outputTask = outputPipe.availableData.joined()
    async let errorTask  = errorPipe.availableData.joined()

    try process.run()

    let outputData = await outputTask
    let errorData = await errorTask

    …
}
```

Where:

```swift
extension Pipe.AsyncAvailableData {
    func joined() async -> Data {
        var data = Data()
        for await availableData in self {
            data.append(availableData)
        }
        return data
    }
}
```

---

Note, I created an asynchronous sequence of the `Data` representing the `availableData` supplied to the `readabilityHandler`. Often, I would create an `AsyncSequence` of the individual bytes of data as shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76941591/1271826. That way, if you wanted to process them line by line, you get that behavior for free. But if you just load the whole stream in memory at one time, then there is no need to add that overhead of converting the sequence of `Data` to a stream of bytes and then back to one large `Data`.

---

While I hope I answered your question above, for the sake of future readers, I must note that there are serious downsides to attempting to load all of the `standardOutput` and `standardError` into their respective `Data`. Specifically, you will have to load the full output in memory at the same time.

We would generally want to process the data *as it comes in,* rather than ever trying to hold the whole thing in memory at one time. In trivial use-cases, loading the whole thing into RAM works fine, but as the input grows, it becomes less and less practical. Caveat emptor.

Comment: Thanks Rob! This app originated in 2009, a decade before continuations debuted. And in this case the output from the pipes is JSON, so it's impossible to parse it until it's all collected. The quantity is known and relatively small. macOS does not share iOS's memory limitations, so this approach works fine for my case. The general warning, however, is valid.

Comment: There is one flaw here: awaiting `outputTask` and `errorTask` alone does not guarantee that `Process` is finished running by the time execution picks back up after the  two `await`s. Wrapping the termination callback into a continuation solves this and prevents us from having to stuff ensuing logic into the completion handler closure.